# Load HTML from file and append it at the end of the body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, vaadin7

I run into a problem while loading some HTML from file and inserting it into the page. Basically I have a HTML page whose body tag has a few other HTML elements in it and what I'm trying to do is to insert some extra HTML from file at the end of the body tag but without removing what's currently in that body tag.
I'm using this to inject the HTML:

```
$("body").load("VAADIN/html/test.html", function(){ 
    var $HTMLob = $(this);
});
```

The HTML snipped is inserted OK but everything else inside the body tag is removed. Is there a way around this and leave everything else in the body tag and append the new HTML at the end of the body tag? I tried to use appendTo() but to no avail, any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("VAADIN/html/test.html", function(result){ 
   $("body").append(result);
});
```

Have you tried something like this?

Comment: No, I didn't actually, I just thought I could do it with load(). Your code works very well : - )! Is it possible to achieve the same result with load() or there are situations when you want to use load() and others when you want to use $.get? I have to admit I did have a look at the Jquery API but nothing evident there made me think to use one or the other, so I 'picked' load()

Comment: @antobbo you probably could use `$('body').append( $('<div />').load('page.html') )`

Comment: @antobbo as i said in my answer `load`replace all the content of the selector.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ thanks, posted mine before reading yours. I also turned that HTML into a jquery object by doing this `var $HTMLob = $(result);`, whereas with load() I can use $(this) directly, but nevermind, it's good as it is now, thanks for your answers guys

Comment: @antobbo Check the answer that solved your question. Thanks :)

Comment: @freedomn-m mine? Is an answer. I wrote the right code for his problem

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah you're right. I wrote so because maybe antobbo alrady tried with $.get. Anyway next time I will write a better answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`.load` function replace all the content of the matching slector with the retreived content.

So you should use `$.get` instead and `append`, like this:

```
$.get("VAADIN/html/test.html", function(data){ 
    $(document).append(data);
});
```